# What does this LLVM 1.5 warning mean? "protocol qualifiers without 'id' is archaic"

Tags: iphone, xcode, llvm

I've just tried compiling an iOS project using the the LLVM 1.5 compiler (included in XCode 3.2.3), and I got a lot of new warnings, including several like this:

```
protocol qualifiers without 'id' is archaic
```

For instance, this happens on lines like this:

```
- (id)initWithContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
          coordinator:(NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)coordinator
             delegate:(<NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>)delegate;
```

Now, I think this is probably a "naming conventions" warning, but anyone know what it really means?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Archaic: [extremely old or extremely old-fashioned](http://www.google.com/dictionary?aq=f&langpair=en|en&q=archaic&hl=en).

The warning means a protocol qualifier (i.e. `<NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>`) without an `id` is deprecated. The delegate parameter's type should look like:

```
- (id)initWithContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
          coordinator:(NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)coordinator
             delegate:(id<NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>)delegate;
       //              ^^
```