# XCODE protocol qualifiers without id is archaic

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, syntax-error

i'm a begginer xcode developer and usign the xcode 4 trying follow a xcode 3.2 tutorial the IDE show me the error;

protocol qualifiers without id is archaic

how i can solve it, what is the correct declaration

tutorial;
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Rd9TtG3Uws

code;

```
<UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate> {

    NSArray* activities;
    NSArray* fellings;
}
```

Comment: What timecode in the video is that?

Comment: did you end up figuring this out?

Comment: Your code is unclear. Can you provide details as to which file of your class (.h or .m) you wrote this in, and where in that file you wrote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare the interface, it inherits from a base class such as NSObject, UIView, UIViewController etc...  You need the interface name, then the base class then the delegates it supports.

Something like this:

```
@interface MyView: UIView <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate> {
    NSArray* activities;
    NSArray* fellings;
}
```

Also, if you're implementing an object that expects something that implements that protocol you should accept id in the signature.  Fr example:

```
- (id)initWithContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
          coordinator:(NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)coordinator
             delegate:(id<NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>)delegate;
```

See this SO question with the same error:

[What does this LLVM 1.5 warning mean? "protocol qualifiers without 'id' is archaic"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094124/what-does-this-llvm-1-5-warning-mean-protocol-qualifiers-without-id-is-archai)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have

```
@interface Classname : InheritedClassname
```

before the <